# Replacing 'this' instance of a Backbone Model with a fetched one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, parse-platform

I'm trying to make loading my model easier. If the model isn't already fetched, it simply uses the `id` field and fetches itself. I then use `_.extend(this, fetchedModel)` to update `this`. The problem is now I'm running into cyclic activities when I try to set this fetched and extended model as a property in another model — `othermodel.set("fetchedModel", fetchedModel)`.

Is there another way to fetch my model and simply overwrite the entire current instance of `this` with what was just fetched?

Here's my code for context (I'm using Parse, as well):

```
load : function(success) {
    debug("Loading workout...");

    // if it's not grabbed, grab it
    if(!this.createdAt) {
        var q = new Parse.Query(Workout);
        q.include("user");
        return q.get(this.id, {
            success : function(workout) {
                _.extend(this, workout);
                this.load(success);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite recursion is caused by the success callback in the method `load` calling `this.load`, i.e. itself.

To reset the attributes of the model, `_.extend(this, workout)` is not the correct way to go. That will copy the properties of `workout` into the model object itself. What you want to do is to update the model's internal `attributes` object using [`Model#set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

```
this.set(workout);
```

If you want to ensure that the new properties not only override old properties, but also clear out any previous properties not present in the new object, also call [`Model#clear`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear):

```
this.clear();
this.set(workout);
```

As an aside, typically to update Backbone model, you would simply call [`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch), like so:

```
this.fetch({
  success: function() {
    //model has been updated...
  }
});
```

Alas, I don't know what's the best practice with parse.com. The documentation for `Parse.Object` [seems to mention the fetch method](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#fetch).